# what would be the approach to building an nft marketplace in solana

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, nft

I am trying to build a full stack NFT market place in Solana. I have a few questions

1. Where will I store the NFT image and metadata everytime an NFT is minted?
2. How do I gather all the NFTs minted on my market place and display them for sale(storefront)

I looked up metaplex storefront but it was deprecated. Should I go with metaplex storefront?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can store the NFT Images and Metadata at Arweave, IPFS or any other storage provider you would prefer.
2. Yes StoreFront was deprecated long time back and if you want to build out a NFT Marketplace you could better use auction-house contract to build your own marketplace you can check the docs [here](https://docs.metaplex.com/programs/auction-house/overview)

Comment: biggest problem I have with IPFS / Arweave is latency. A storefront is better off caching high frequency images in a centralized server where latency can be reduced.

Answer (score 1):

Building an NFT marketplace is demanding for small teams, but an SDK could help a lot with the whole process. Here's a quick walkthrough of an example:

1. Choose a blockchain platform to create the tokens on.
2. Design the in-game assets that they want to create.
3. Create a smart contract on the blockchain platform.
4. Integrate the smart contract into their game.
5. Once the game is launched and players start playing, the smart contract will automatically mint new tokens and distribute them to players according to the rules defined in the contract.

If you were to **create an NFT collection** in the game, in Mirror World Smart SDK, the whole process would take less than 10 minutes to deploy, which would be significant compared to doing all the steps above all over again.

All you have to do is to enter a couple of different attributes, upload or generate the NFT pictures or any in-game asset you would like to make, and the asset would be on-chain as you wanted.

The SDK would handle the complexities of **interacting with the blockchain and managing the smart contract**, allowing the developer to focus on the design and gameplay of their game and users to list and sell their items using the in-game wallet. I used some information from this guide as a reference: https://blog.mirrorworld.fun/p/benefits-of-minting-nfts-metaverse.

Hope that helps!